# Regex - Something before or after without groups?

Tags: regex

I want to match any of the following cases:

```
blue car
car blue
red car
car red
```

And i'm using this pattern:
`/(car\s)?(red|blue)(\scar)?/`

But this pattern will match also `red`or `blue` without the word `car` before/after.

Any way to do this without using groups or multiple patterns?

Comment: `/((red|blue)\scar)|(car\s(red|blue))/`     ?

Comment: did you want to match `foo blue car` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditional subpattern for this in PCRE:

```
(?:\b(car)\s+)?\b(?:red|blue)\b(?(1)\s*|\s+car\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oS9xP3/4)

Comment: Everything is okay except your pattern will match `car randomtext red` and that's wrong.

Comment: so it has to be next or previous word from `car`?

Comment: Yes, before or after the word `car`.